# AWK -- How to do selective multiple column sorting?

Tags: sorting, awk, multiple-columns

In awk, how can I do this:

Input:

```
1  a  f  1  12  v  
2  b  g  2  10  w  
3  c  h  3  19  x  
4  d  i  4  15  y  
5  e  j  5  11  z
```

Desired output, by sorting numerical value at `$5`:

```
1  a  f  2  10  w  
2  b  g  5  11  z  
3  c  h  1  12  v  
4  d  i  4  15  y  
5  e  j  3  19  x
```

**Note** that the sorting should **only** affecting `$4`, `$5`, and `$6` (based on value of `$5`), in which the previous part of table remains intact.

Comment: Do you mean columns `$4`, `$5`, and `$6`? AWK starts at 1 :)

Comment: You're right. It's a typo. Thanks for the correction and the solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be done in multiple steps with the help of [`paste`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/paste-invocation.html):

```
$ gawk '{print $1, $2, $3}' in.txt > a.txt
$ gawk '{print $4, $5, $6}' in.txt | sort -k 2 -n b.txt > b.txt
$ paste -d' ' a.txt b.txt
1 a f 2 10 w
2 b g 5 11 z
3 c h 1 12 v
4 d i 4 15 y
5 e j 3 19 x
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of any other solution without calling external function? Just wonder if it's possible (but may be too tricky to perform)

Comment: `sort` and `paste` are not 'external functions' but basic Unix tools. They allow you to build very flexible solutions.

Comment: This doesnt work when the 5th column of original has numbers greater than 19 and less than 10

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I find using `awk` to safely sort arrays of columns rather tricky because often you will need to hold and sort on duplicate keys. If you need to selectively sort a group of columns, I would call `paste` for some assistance:

```
paste -d ' ' <(awk '{ print $1, $2, $3 }' file.txt) <(awk '{ print $4, $5, $6 | "sort -k 2" }' file.txt)
```

Results:

```
1 a f 2 10 w
2 b g 5 11 z
3 c h 1 12 v
4 d i 4 15 y
5 e j 3 19 x
```

Answer (score 4):

This *can* be done in pure `awk`, but as @steve said, it's not ideal.  `gawk` has limited sort functions, and `awk` has no built-in sort at all. That said, here's a (rather hackish) solution using a compare function in `gawk`:

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp3]$ cat text 
1  a  f  1  12  v  
2  b  g  2  10  w  
3  c  h  3  19  x  
4  d  i  4  15  y  
5  e  j  5  11  z  
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp3]$ cat doit.gawk 
### Function to be called by asort().
function cmp(i1,v1,i2,v2) {
  split(v1,a1); split(v2,a2);
  if (a1[2]>a2[2])      { return 1; }
  else if (a1[2]<a2[2]) { return -1; }
  else                  { return 0; }
}

### Left-hand-side and right-hand-side, are sorted differently.
{
  lhs[NR]=sprintf("%s %s %s",$1,$2,$3);
  rhs[NR]=sprintf("%s %s %s",$4,$5,$6);
}

END {
  asort(rhs,sorted,"cmp");    ### This calls the function we defined, above.
  for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {       ### Step through the arrays and reassemble.
    printf("%s %s\n",lhs[i],sorted[i]);
  }
}    
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp3]$ gawk -f doit.gawk text 
1 a f 2 10 w
2 b g 5 11 z
3 c h 1 12 v
4 d i 4 15 y
5 e j 3 19 x
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp3]$
```

This keeps your entire input file in arrays, so that lines can be reassembled after the sort.  If your input is millions of lines, this may be problematic.

Note that you might want to play with the `printf` and `sprintf` functions to set appropriate output field separators.

You can find documentation on using `asort()` with functions in the gawk man page; look for `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`.

Comment: I did try to do this using only `GNU awk`, but I gave up after about 20 minutes. I knew it wasn't impossible +1